# Can I decompile a x86 library, then compile it to ARM?

Tags: x86, arm, shared-libraries, cross-compiling, decompiling

I know this is really hard, but I have a library that is in x86, and I want to compile it to ARM to run it on my Rasberry Pi. I've read that some software like Hex-Rays is capable of decompiling, after doing so, is it easy to recompile to arm? Or this mission is impossible?

Comment: I believe there are a few projects around that will do direct binary translation

Comment: it is possible to do semi-automated, you will have to tweak the process though as it is not really something you can just get a tool to do.  And then there is the issue of system calls which you are going to have to simulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the decompiler you choose spits out actual C code and not pseudocode (some do), it should just be a matter of adding a few extra flags to your compiler (if you use gcc, these are usually prefaced by -m. [See here for gnu's docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html)).  As far as I know, though, most decompilers only work with 32-bit x86, so you may be out of luck if your library is 64-bit.  There are also toolchains that are specifically designed for this task, although many of them come packaged with IDEs (check out tools like  [Codesourcery](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/codesourcery) ).

Good luck